# Windows Backup error 0x80070020 MasterFileStatus.db

Tags: windows, backup

I am using Windows Backup and creating a system state backup. First time it works, but during next backups I have the following error.

Error in deletion of [C:\System Volume Information\MasterFileStatus.db] while pruning the target VHD. Error [0x80070020] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Has anybody face this error and know how to resolved?

I've been trying things like disabling antivirus, recreating volume, different shadow copy backup options, but now I'm running out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Just find out that these failed it was produced due to Acronis Backups Tool.

I'm not sure how it works but it seems that Acronis uses shadow copy as well and it blocks the possibility to create differential backups.

That's why only allow you to perform one backup but not to schedule new ones over it.

There are two solutions in case, use only one of these tools to perform backups or if you want to use both for any particular reason, write an script to move and delete old backups, every time you should generate a new one that it would take much more time to complete than using differential backups but it works.